# Why isn't data being returned to the getJSON success handler?

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I was calling `getJSON` and looping through the results like this and everything was working great:

```
$.getJSON( base_url + 'search/drill_down',{
        nextSelectName: nextSelectName,
        thisSelectName: thisSelectName,
        itemId: itemId
    }, function( r ) {
        $.each( r.items, function( k, v ) {
            //do stuff
        });
});
```

Now on a certain condition I need to return some HTML data, but I still need JSON for my original condition, so I figured I would just encode my HTML as JSON, but the data never returns!  The original code still works fine, it is only when I'm trying to return HTML encoded as JSON that things blow up.

```
$.getJSON( base_url + 'search/drill_down',{
        nextSelectName: nextSelectName,
        thisSelectName: thisSelectName,
        itemId: itemId
    }, function( r ) {

        alert('working!'); // Not hitting this!

        if(r.tabs){
            $.each( r.tabs, function( k, v ) {
            var html = v[ 'html' ];
                return $('#content').html(html); // No need to continue, there is only one HTML string and no items.
            });
        }

        $.each( r.items, function( k, v ) { 
            //do stuff
        });
});
```

I have a break point on the server (using CodeIgniter) and everything there looks good.  I checked checked the HTML I encoded as JSON and it is valid JSON.  Why is the JSON generated by my server not making it back to the `getJSON` success handler?

Comment: mayb check the response you are getting from the server.. and make sure the complete response you are getting back has the correct datatype and is valid JSON.. you can do this by using the developer tools of the browser you are using to test ur site

Comment: @ParvSharma Thanks, but as I stated, I am not getting any response back.  The first bit of code in the success handler is `alert('working!')` and I'm not even hitting that. I also stated that I put a break point on the server and checked the data it generated and verified it was valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation is the request was flaud, and reason might be many. One might be requesting on a wrong place. Check using

```
console.log(base_url + 'search/drill_down');
```

Comment: Thanks, `console.log()` allowed me to identify a server error that was messing up my JSON after the point I had checked its validity.